# Translating Excel formula to c# (annuity)

Tags: c#

I have a excel formula I am trying to "translate" into c# code.

It is used to calculate an "annuity rate" over time (for example 20 years).

```
=(((1+E26/100)^D28*((1+E26/100)-1))/((1+E26/100)^D28-1))*100
```

*D28 = 20* (years)

*E26 = 5,00* (the rate in percent)

*the **^** stands for exponent in Excel*

As a result with these numbers I expect 8,02% per annum.

I tried several approaches using Math.Pow but wasn't successful.

Here is my first approach which gives me a result of 5 somehow.

```
double usagePanels = 20.0
double rate = 5.0
annPanels = (Math.Pow((1 + rate / 100), usagePanels) *
           ((1 + rate / 100) - 1) /
           Math.Pow(1+rate/100, (usagePanels-1))) * 100;
```

Thank you.

Comment: It would be so much easier to see what you did wrong if you actually showed what you did.

Comment: Would you mind showing what you tried as well?

Comment: Without seeing the code I cannot be sure, but my suspicion is that you have rounding errors.

Comment: The problem is probably with your division. If you're plugging in 20 for D28, for example, 20/100 = 0 in integer math. Try casting one of the values to double: (double)20/100 = 0.2

Comment: If you're using literals, use `20.0` instead of `20`. `20` is an `int` and `20.0` is a `double`.

Comment: added more info to my initial post

Comment: I would break the formula apart in both Excel and C# and then compare.  This ought to allow you to see where it is no doing what you expect.  i.e try `=((1+E26/100)^D28*((1+E26/100)-1))` and `=((1+E26/100)^D28-1)` in excel and replicate in C#.

Comment: When I enter this formula into Excel I get 5.02% not 8.02%, are you sure that you are expecting 8.02? Try it with a bran new Excel sheet and you'll see that the value of 5.026292 is valid.

Comment: @NikolaD-Nick No, when i enter '=(((1+5/100)^20*((1+5/100)-1))/((1+5/100)^20-1))*100' in a blank cell I get 8,02

Comment: @Grhm You know what? That did the trick. What a great tip, seriously ;) It works now. The 'usagePanels-1' was not placed well. Should i answer my own question then? How to credit you? ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
double usagePanels = 20.0
double rate = 5.0
double annPanels = (Math.Pow((1 + rate / 100), usagePanels) *
         (rate / 100.0)) /
         Math.Pow(1+rate/100, usagePanels)-1)) * 100;
```

You've got the closing bracket, between `usagePanels` and the `-1`, wrong...

(I found this by breaking the formula apart in Excel and in C# and comparing each part.)

EDIT: Another handy tip for comparing Excel to C# is to give the cells in Excel a name (via the Named Range feature) that way the Excel formula can be made to look closer to variable names...

Comment: almost, after your tip, I did that and yeah, -1 was in the wrong place. here is my current working code

'annPanels = (Math.Pow((1 + rate / 100), usagePanels) * ((1 + rate / 100) - 1) / (Math.Pow(1+rate/100, (usagePanels))-1)) * 100;'

Comment: @theserpent: You also don't need the `(1+rate/100)-1` You're adding and removeing one. `rate/100.0` will suffice

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
double rate = 5;
double years = 20;
double annunity = Math.Pow(1 + rate / 100, years) * (rate / 100) / Math.Pow(1 + rate / 100, years - 1) * 100;
```

Comment: that looks almost exactly like my approach. but this results in 5.25 instead of 8.02
i cant wrap my head around this.

Comment: look at your excel solution:

`/((1+E26/100)^D28-1))*100`

In `^D28-1`, the power of D28 takes precedence over the -1, I think you want to add put the `D28-1` in parentheses, or add the -1 outside the `Pow` in the C#

Comment: After following advice to break the formula down, what you said is exactly what I noticed and did the trick now.

Answer (score 2):

For clarity, the working result is

```
double usagePanels = 20.0
double rate = 5.0
annPanels = (Math.Pow((1 + rate / 100), usagePanels) *
       ((1 + rate / 100) - 1) /
       (Math.Pow(1+rate/100, (usagePanels))-1)) * 100;
```

Thanks to Jason Allen and Grhm who basically figured it out and gave great advice.